# Excel / VBA - How to select the top row (absolute) of whichever column (relative) the currently selected cell is in?

Tags: excel, vba

I spent 11 hours a few days ago ripping my brain apart to do this. Everyone either answers using sample ranges with absolute values, or with the entirely relative .offset function. Or they mention it's not good to select in vba, or they provide a workaround of some sort that I can't adapt, or .select doesn't work with R1C1...etc, etc. My script is done now, and fully functioning with the following loop code, but it's SLOW because it uses this loop about 2000-3000 times each time the macro runs:

```
Do Until Selection.Row = 1
    If Selection.Row <> 1 Then
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop
```

I just want to know, for whichever cell is currently selected, wherever it is, is there a faster way in vba to .Select the top row (row #1, absolute reference) of that (any) column (relative reference)?

Comment: Doesn't something like this: `Selection.Offset(1 - Selection.Row).Select` fix it?

Comment: sigh... where were you when I started...i might have some hairs left :D haha thank you!! That worked great!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate to find the top of the current column:

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Activate
```

The `.End(xlUp)` member of a `Range` finds the end of the *contiguous* data set. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel).

or

```
Cells(1, Selection.Column).Activate
```

This method uses the `Column` member of a `Range` to return the *number* of that column, then uses the `Cells` function to call the first row of that column. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel).

or (as mentioned)

```
Selection.Offset(1 - Selection.Row).Select
```

This method uses the `Offset` member of a `Range`. This function ([more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)) has two optional parameters. The first is `RowOffset`, so this formula will offset a cell in A21 by -20 rows, thus giving A1.

*Edited for more information and references*

Comment: thank you! this worked! you know it is almost impossible to find more data on this particular function online. hopefully this helps someone!! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For do it faster you can optimize like this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do Until Selection.Row = 1
    If Selection.Row <> 1 Then
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

One question, you can not use Cells(x,y).row instead of Selection metod ? This is a faster way.

In other way, the column normaly have a name in top, you can search this name and get this position an select the row below.
Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim intColumn As Integer
intColumn = ObtainColumn(Range("A1:F1"), "NameColum")
intRow = ObtainRow(Range("A1:A10"), "NameColum")
Cells(intRow, intColumn).Select

End Sub


Function ObtainColumn(rng As Range, strValue As String) As Long
Dim lCol As Long
'Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
On Error Resume Next
lCol = 0
lCol = rng.Find(What:=strValue, _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
    ObtainColumn = lCol
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function ObtainRow(rng As Range, strValue As String) As Long
Dim lRow As Long
'Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
lRow = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    lRow = rng.Find(What:=strValue, _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
    ObtainRow = lRow
    On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: In other way, the column normaly have a name in top, you can search this name and get this position an select the row below.

Comment: Thanks for offering your help! I tried the function given in the first comment and it worked perfectly. But thanks for your advice here! Had that not worked I might have tried this, and perhaps your answer here will help someone else down the road. Thanks!